# JSON parser in Java using Map

Tags: java, json, parsing, mapping

I'm trying to parse a json file using the org.json.simple library and I'm getting null pointer exception when I try to instantiate the iterator with the Map.

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static void main(String[] args) {

    JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();

    try {

        Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader("wadingpools.json"));

        JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;
        System.out.println(jsonObject);

        JSONArray featuresArray = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("features");
        Iterator iter = featuresArray.iterator();

        while (iter.hasNext()) {
            Map<String, String> propertiesMap = ((Map<String, String>) jsonObject.get("properties"));
            Iterator<Map.Entry<String, String>> itrMap = propertiesMap.entrySet().iterator();
            while(itrMap.hasNext()){
                Map.Entry<String, String> pair = itrMap.next();
                System.out.println(pair.getKey() + " : " + pair.getValue());
            }
        }

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

}

Here is a snippet of part of the JSON file. I'm trying to get the NAME in the properties object.

```
{
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "crs": {
        "type": "name",
        "properties": {
            "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84"
        }
    },
    "features": [{
            "type": "Feature",
            "properties": {
                "PARK_ID": 393,
                "FACILITYID": 26249,
                "NAME": "Wading Pool - Crestview",
                "NAME_FR": "Pataugeoire - Crestview",
                "ADDRESS": "58 Fieldrow St."
            },
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At `(Map<String, String>) jsonObject.get("properties")` you are trying to access `properties` from your "root" object (held by `jsonObject`) which *doesn't have such key*. You probably wanted to get value of that key from object held by `features` array. You already created iterator for that array, but you never used it to get elements held by it. You need something like

```
while (iter.hasNext()) {
    JSONObject tmpObject = (JSONObject) iter.next();
    ...
}
```

and call `get("properties")` on that `tmpObject`.

Comment: @VincentArrage You are welcome. BTW you should take a look at [How to efficiently iterate over each entry in a 'Map'?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46898). Explicitly using iterator is nice if you want to modify map (like remove some entries). If you just want to print its elements code using for-each may be easier to write and maintain.